# Where to set IN criteria (Parent table or Child table) in mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We have two tables (Customer and Order) table. Is there any performance difference between these two queries given below.

1. Customer table has customer details.(customerId, customerdetails)
2. Order table has Order details of the customer(orderId, customerId, orderdetails) i.e customer id will be duplicated here and not nullable with ON_DELETE_CASCADE foreign key.

eg query:

```
select * from Order where customerId in (1,2,3,4,....)
```

or

```
 select Order.* from Order inner join customer on 
 Order.customerId = customer.customerId where customer.customerId 
 in (1,2,3,4,....)
```

Comment: There is a slight difference in performance. With proper indexing it is negligible

Comment: If the data from `customer` is needed in neither output nor filtering then it must not present in the query. The performance degrade can be any - from undetectable till dramatic, depends on many factors.

Comment: The queries are formally not equivalent and can give different outputs until `order.customerId` is defined as foreign key to `customer.customerId` and NOT NULL.

Comment: the first query should be faster as no join but what about keys? Where do you have keys?

Answer (score 0):

The first one does less work: it only references one table. Therefore it's faster.

The second one has an `INNER JOIN`.  That means it must check each `Order` row to ensure it has a matching `Customer` row. (If a Customer is DELETEd, her orders won't appear in the result set.) Rows that don't match must not appear in the result set.  Doing that check takes at least some work. But if your tables are small you'll probably be unable to measure any significant difference.

You can investigate this yourself by prefixing [EXPLAIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/) to each query. It tells you how the query planner module will satisfy the query. Your second query will have two EXPLAIN rows.

Indexes will help. Your first query will benefit if you create this one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Order CREATE INDEX customerId (customerId);
```

Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you have other [query-optimization](/questions/tagged/query-optimization) questions, you probably should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info).

Answer (score 0):

A *General Rule*:  One query involving two tables and a `JOIN` will be faster than two queries where you are handing ids from the first to the second.  And it is less code (once you are familiar with Joins).

Why?  A roundtrip from the client to the server takes some effort.  Two roundtrips is slower than one.

Does it matter?  Not a lot.  Usually, the difference is millisecond(s), maybe less.

Always?  No.  That is why I said "General Rule".